# Non-exhaustive patterns in function s

Tags: haskell

I have a simple program as:

```
s (x1:x2:xs) = print(x1) >> print(x2) >> s xs
main = s [5,4,1,1]
```

But it produces the following error:

```
Non-exhaustive patterns in function s
```

I have tried a lot to fix this error. Need some help here.

Comment: What's the result of `s []`?

Comment: `s [] = 0` I guess. But it gives me an error if I do this

Comment: Using `-Wall` will detect this error at compile time instead of runtime.

Comment: @ZubinKadva How can Haskell make `s [] = 0` when the code does not specify what to do in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just applying `s` definition over the given data:

```
s [5, 4, 1, 1]
print 5 >> print 4 >> s [1, 1]
print 5 >> print 4 >> print 1 >> print 1 >> s []
-- error: s [] is not defined
```

You just need to add the case in the patterns:

```
s [] = return ()
s (x1:x2:xs) = ...
```

Note this still fails for `s [5]`.

Comment: Well, it fixes the non-exhaustive error. Can you tell me what is the type for `s`? Sorry, but I am new to Haskell

Comment: @ZubinKadva if you use GHCi, you can type `:type s` to find out the type. Here, the type is `IO ()`.

Comment: Thanks, but entering the following code `s :: Show a => [a] -> IO b` gives me an error

Comment: Oh right, lack of attention on my part, that is the correct type.